# How can I unbind this .click action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make this switch function so that when the on button is already clicked and the person clicks off, the on buttons CSS goes back to normal. I also want the switch to be set already on default. I've tried that too but had no luck.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Toggleswitch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="switch-container">
        <button id="darkmodeon">ON</button>
        <button id="darkmodeoff">OFF</button>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
}

.switch-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 135px;

}

#darkmodeon{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: none;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    font-family:"calibri light";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

#darkmodeoff{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: none;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    font-family:"calibri light";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var darkon = "#darkmodeon";
    var darkoff = "#darkmodeoff";

    $(darkon).click(function(){
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "#66e86a",
            "color": "white" ,
            "transition": "all 0.3s ease"   
        });
    });

    $(darkoff).click(function(){
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "#66e86a",
            "color": "white" ,
            "transition": "all 0.3s ease"   
        });
        $(this).unbind('click', darkon);
    });



});
```

Comment: `unbind` has been deprecated for a number of releases. Use `off` to remove event handlers.

Comment: I have used your code with my localhost. The switch is not working as a switch. I can click both On and Off and both go green.

Comment: you gave me the idea to use checkboxes instead of buttons thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.click(handler)` is just a surrogate for `.on('click', handler)`. To remove any handler previously bound to any event, on any element, use:

```
$(selector).off('eventName', handler)
```

Example:

```js
var whatever = function(){
    // code here
};
$(selector).on('click', whatever); // or $(selector).click(handler);
$(selector).off('click', whatever);
```

While exemplifying how to unbind, the above example doesn't do much, because the function is unbound immediately after it was bound. Typically, you'd unbind based on your app's logic.

For example, if you want to unbind a `click` after first `click`, typically you'd use `.off()` inside the bound function:

```js
var whatever = function(){
  $(this).off('click', whatever);
  // code that only runs on first click.
};
$(selector).on('click', whatever); // or $(selector).click(handler);
```

---

As for your example, why don't you just toggle a class on their parent?

```js
$('.parent button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.parent').toggleClass('on');
})
```

```css
/*.parent button, 
.parent.on button:first-child {
  display: none;
}
.parent button:first-child,
.parent.on button:last-child {
  display: inline;
}*/

/* if you don't want/like the animation, just use the simple `display` switch above */

.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent button {
  transition: opacity .2s linear, transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
.parent.on button:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.parent button:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%)
}
.parent button:first-child,
.parent.on button:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <button>On</button>
  <button>Off</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbuN2286, please note I made a small addition to the toggle example above. If you're going to use it in production, it needs [prefixing](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).